# What happens when you release an expired domain?

Tags: domains, domain-transfer, expires

I've got a domain on a registrar, which is in its grace period. I'd like to move it to a new registrar, so I think releasing it will be the best option. I had the impression releasing a domain name makes it available for registration again, but I have a worrying warning from my old registrar when about to release it:

> **Important!**
>   I understand that re-tagging my domain will remove it from my account and I have already initiated a transfer with my new provider and they are expecting the domain domain.com.

Unfortunately I haven't initiated a transfer as I can't obtain EPP codes from an expired domain name.

My question is should I ignore the warning, go ahead to release the domain name? If I do, would it be immediately available for re-registration? If I haven't initiated the transfer on a new registrar, what would happen after I release it?

Comment: Is this for a .uk domain?  As far as I know they are the only ones with "tagging".

Comment: @Steve I thought so too, but strangely, it's a .com domain. However, it's controlled by Netistrar which I believe is the UK registrar for .uk domains

Comment: There are no notions of "tag" in .COM. It does not work as .UK. If you gave the real domain name you would have better replies. See ICANN gTLD lifecycle that explains what happens when a name expire: https://archive.icann.org/en/registrars/gtld-lifecycle.jpg Once the domain is really deleted you risk that anyone can register it before you. It is not the good way to proceed. You should instead renew it, wait 2 months and then transfer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've got a domain on a registrar, which is in its grace period. I'd
>   like to move it to a new registrar, so I think releasing it will be
>   the best option. I had the impression releasing a domain name makes it
>   available for registration again, but I have a worrying warning from
>   my old registrar when about to release it

The terminology you are using is quite unclear. But you should **not** delete the domain name. In general the registrar will send the name to redemption, rather than truly delete it on the spot.

This is not the way to do it.
To transfer a .com to another registrar you need to:

- release the registrar-lock on the domain name (if active)
- obtain the EPP code
- initiate the transfer from the new registrar, they will need
  the the EPP code
- you may receive some mails asking to click a link to approve the transfer then the whole process can take a few days, or a few hours - with some registrars you can expedite the process by approving early

I repeat, do not try to have the domain name deleted in any circumstances. You might lose it forever.

> Unfortunately I haven't initiated a transfer as I can't obtain EPP
>   codes from an expired domain name.

As per Icann rules you should be able to transfer a domain name even if it has expired but good luck enforcing them. But taking into account that the name has already expired, the grace period varies from one registrar to another. Some registrars have **zero** grace period, and will send the domain to redemption the very next day after expiry.

I would advise you to renew the domain and retry the transfer later but not at the last minute.

Answer (score 1):

A registrar detags a domain because for some reason they are assuming you don't want to renew.  The detagging ensures that they are not billed by the registry for a domain you seemingly don't want.

There don't seem to be any information on whether the domain becomes available *immediately* for registration.

Comment: Op mentions "EPP code", which would refer to a gTLD. Detagging only applies to .uk domains.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins Yep.  I mentioned that in my comment on the question.